# If not exist the file like that form ask second time (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file, return

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /P build1=Please enter the first build name:
IF NOT EXIST %build1% ECHO '%build1%' doesn't exist, please provide valid build. 

SET /P build2=Please enter the second build name:
IF NOT EXIST %build2% ECHO '%build2%' doesn't exist, please provide valid build.
```

How can I set a function that will ask me "Please enter the valid build name" if I write the name that will not be similar like "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###" on "Please enter the first build name" step. 
The same thing for the second build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WINDOWS 10 64-BIT.

How to partially validate cmd `set /p` input.

[How to secure your set /p input](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_inputvalidation_setp.php)

```
@title Enter the build name in "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###"  format.
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. Does not require admin privileges.
@echo off 
SETLOCAL enableextensions
ECHO. 
ECHO    Enter the build name
ECHO    in    "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###" format w/ quotes.  ### must be three numbers.
ECHO    i.e.  "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v546"
ECHO.
:build1
SET /P build1="Please enter the build1 name: "
set errorlevel=
ECHO %build1% | findstr /i /r /c:INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v[0-9][0-9][0-9]>nul || set build1=
IF NOT DEFINED build1 (
ECHO. 
ECHO Enter the build name in "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###" format w/ quotes.  ### must be three numbers.
ECHO ^(i.e. "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v546"^)
goto :build1     
)
IF NOT EXIST %build1% (
ECHO %build1% doesn't exist, please provide valid build.
goto :build1 
)
REM what you want to do to build1 here
:build2
SET /P build2="Please enter the build2 name: "
set errorlevel=
ECHO %build2% | findstr /i /r /c:INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v[0-9][0-9][0-9]>nul || set build2=
IF NOT DEFINED build2 (
ECHO. 
ECHO Enter the build name in "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###" format w/ quotes.  ### must be three numbers.
ECHO ^(i.e. "INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v546"^)
goto :build2     
)
IF NOT EXIST %build2% (
ECHO %build2% doesn't exist, please provide valid build.
goto :build2 
)
REM what you want to do to build2 here
exit /b
```

[Powershell: The many ways to use regex](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/)

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/)

[Verify if Variables are Defined](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_defined.php)

[If](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php)

[Findstr](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php)

[Findstr and regex](https://www.windows-commandline.com/findstr-command-examples-regular/)

Comment: Quick question...What happens if I enter **`\ `** at the `Set /P` prompt? I would suggest that input would pass the `If Defined` test, and also the `If Exist` test. You therefore have not validated anything because **`\ `** certainly doesn't follow the required naming convention, and you haven't checked to see if it does.

Comment: No it isn't @GorArakelyan, please read my previous comment, and try it!

Comment: When I entered in the "Please enter the build1 name:" a name that's exist in that folder but it's not in the folowing format the script is working.

Comment: @GorArakelyan, try entering **`\ `**, _like I stated in my opening comment_.

Comment: @com better? any other improvements?

Comment: Not the most wise thing to ask, somebadhat, it would be much simpler for me to just post an answer myself rather than to'ing and fro'ing in the comments until your answer becomes more robust. I'm not going to do that because I see no purpose in requesting this kind of input. I doubt that many typists can enter `INTERNAL-TEST-Kestrel-Firmware-internal-test-v###` at the prompt quicker than using a GUI dialog box. _(it would make far more sense to validate only the trailing digits, i.e. `Set /P "var=Please enter the build version number"`)_.